# JAVA: Send Redirect by Socket

Tags: java, sockets

i like to create a server. The server is listening on a port. If a browser connect to a server the server must send a redirect to a page e.g. server is running on port 4100. You type in the browser:
http://localhost:4100
and the server sends a response to the client and the clients opens the page where redirected to e.g. server sends example.com the clients will load the website example.com

This is my Server-Listener:

```
boolean go = true;
    try {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(4100);
        System.out.println("Listening for connection on port 4100 ....");
        while (go){
          // spin forever
            Socket clientSocket = server.accept();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while (line!=null && !line.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
                System.out.println("REDIRECT CLIENT TO example.com");
out.write("HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\n");
                        out.write("Date: Tue, 11 Jan 2011 13:09:20 GMT\r\n");         
                        out.write("Content-type: text/plain\r\n");
                        out.write("Server: vinit\r\n");           
                        out.write("Location: http://www.example.com\r\n");
                        out.write("Connection: Close");
                        out.write("\r\n\r\n");
                        out.flush();
               
            }
            
        
        server.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But the browser did not load the redirected page. How can i send a redirect to the browser? This server is only for sending a redirect to the client.

Comment: You would need to implement an HTTP server, which is a fairly involved task. Is there a reason you don’t want to use an existing HTTP implementation?

Comment: Yes i dont need a complete HTTP Server. This server sends only a redirect to a specific Website. Nothing more to do. But i can use a http server instead. Do you have a simple example server that sends a redirect?

Comment: Here’s an article with a simple example of implementing an HTTP server. The section showing the request to google.com shows how it responds with a redirect https://dev.to/mateuszjarzyna/build-your-own-http-server-in-java-in-less-than-one-hour-only-get-method-2k02